# Weird character appears after typing "`" followed by "i" on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macbook-pro-retina

When i type "`" followed by "i" i get this character: "ì". The workaround which i'm using now is to type the "i" frist and then move my cursor in-front of "i" and then type "`". But this is a bit annoying...

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ì is a special character in some languages like the é or è or â in french. Normally when typing one of this accents ´`^ or ~, followed by a character for which in some languages these special forms exist, OSX puts them together to create the accented character.

The fastest way, if you want to write things like `i or ´e, is to type the accent (or backtick), then type <kbd>space</kbd>, and then the letter you want to write.

Edit:

If you want to disable the accented characters, this [post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723236/macosx-how-to-disable-accented-characters-input) might help. (I am using a german keyboard, there this does not apply).

Comment: That's better then my previous workaround. But is it possible to disable/turn off that yellow background feature all together? Thanks @P.J.Meisch

Comment: @JoSmo: I added a link to SO how you might disable the accented characters.

Comment: well, I need them sometimes when writing in french or spanish, so I never tried to switch that feature of. But after some time you get used to hitting space after the `´or ^ key, so I can write quite fluently with the accents being above or before the letter, just as I need it.

Comment: I guess that i will just have to get used to it. The space solution makes it a bit more bearable. Thanks again! :)